# Use native libary for iOS and Android (Nativescript)

Tags: android, ios, navigation, nativescript

I'm starting on a project with Nativescript. I want to create an app for Android and iOS. I want to create a navigation bar at the bottom of the screen.. I used a github project for Android for this in another project, but since this is different from native Android I don't know if I can use this..

The github project I mean is: https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar

Is it possible to use this in my Nativescript project and on both Android and iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use it in your project. I almost made a plugin using this lib months ago but no time :) I did start here wih another bottom bar library https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-bottomnavigation reusing native libs is the greatest thing about NativeScript for me and it's pretty easy once you know how to include the library into your project. Which it seems you might know about gradle and android projects so you shouldn't have much trouble :) feel free to look at my plugins or the hundreds of others for help.

Answer (score 0):

I just finished, (in the last hour that is), struggling through getting my first NativeScript plugin going and this [post](http://fluentreports.com/blog/?p=167) was the piece that really helped me.  Like Brad said, once you have the right bits in place, it goes fairly well. :)